# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compiler-errors

I have the code below:
List<XElement>  DBListSetxElements = DbListSetItems[0].Value.Root.Descendants("ListSet").Select(desc => desc.Attribute("Name")).Distinct().ToList();

While compile getting error
**Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'**

Need Help.

Comment: the error ir pretty straightforward, you're trying to cast a list of strings result from Db into a list of XML elements that cant be done implicitily

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to provide the DbListSetItems class definition if you want any more help. Seems you're trying to select the name of the XML element and perhaps in the DbListSetItems data you have the content.

This solution creates a XML Element but the content is null As I said if you want to populate with some other DbListSetItems  property you need to provide us some info (or get the apropiate value from it like `desc.Attribute("theApropiateAtributeNameValue")` ) instead null:

```
        List<XElement> DBListSetxElements = DbListSetItems[0].Value.Root.Descendants("ListSet")
            .Select(desc => new XElement(desc.Attribute("Name"), null)).Distinct().ToList();
```